# VS2010 Ultimate - Unable to launch ASP.NET Development Server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, webdev.webserver

I've worked with ASP.NET once before and had a project where it was potentially useful, so I started creating an ASP.NET website as part of a solution that contained several C# class libraries.

I'm using **Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate Edition** and **Windows 7 Professional x64**. The issue is that when I try to debug my website project, I get the following error message:

*Unable to launch the ASP.NET Development Server*

There's no other information (it seems a popular variant is the "port in use" error).

Interestingly, I can run single pages on the application by right-clicking on the ASPX and selecting "View in Browser". This does not allow me to debug into my breakpoints, though.

I have no clue what the problem could be. I'm running VS2010 in Administrator mode. One of the questions that popped up here suggested I uncomment the "127.0.0.1 localhost" line from my HOSTS file, which I did, and restarted VS with no luck. I also tried both setting a static port for the web server to run on as well as let it dynamically generate one. Both do not help the situation.

Any help?

Thanks.

**Added on 5/20/2010 at 9:25 CT**
I can debug by attaching to the process. However, this is still a painful way to debug quickly so I'd still like a solution to the problem.

Comment: Did you check the Windows Event Viewer for any errors?

Comment: Good suggestion. I was trying to dig around in the VS2010 logs without any success. I will take a look at the event viewer and update this question if there is anything pertinent.

Comment: it could be issue with location of DevServer folder

Comment: Also, the Windows Event Viewer does not have any errors.

Comment: Were you using NOD32 antivirus?

Comment: Nope. I feel like the InstallShield package was doing one or more things that caused several things to crash (one of them being the ASP.NET dev server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I had a InstallShield Lite project which was apparently causing problems. Once I unloaded that project, I can launch the development server in debugging mode.

Answer (score 0):

There are some things to check before listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwesw3ee(VS.71).aspx#vxtbshttpservererrorsthingstocheck)
Please eliminate issues on the link and check whether you may debug

Hope this helps
Myra

Comment: I went through the list and it didn't help solve the issue. The problem does seem to be about debugging, though, since I can start without debugging fine. I'm an administrator and VS2010 is running in admin mode, so I don't think I *need* to add myself to the debugger group, right?